RDS Mysql replica cdc performance
I have a RDS Mysql which has high read/write volume. ~10k IOPS on an average and peaks up to 16k IOPS.
I have another RDS mysql replica of the main. We are using this replica to capture cdc logs and sync to BigQuery. We are using Airbyte for this.
Daily during the daytime lag between main and replica increases a lot and it catches up again at the night when traffic is relatively low.
We have IO2 volume on the replica with provisioned 15k IOPS but I see that total IOPS is capped at around 9k (8k is write and roughly 1k is read). Why is the IOPS capped at 9k?
Are there some optimisations which can help to reduce lag during the day?
